Deleting user's name
I'm so sorry for this post, but I think this is necessary.
Although this site is designed for research, some users misuse it. These users choose a name for its profile that is a vilification. For example this user select the "kire khar" as her/his profiles name.
This name is so bad that I think its meaning cant mention here. Are users have freedom to select the amoral names? 

I assume the Urban Dictionary definitions are the meaning you are refering to?

I reverted the user name to the default user12345 form. If the user would like to change their name to something else, they may use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.
